# Filtering a table with QUERY to get a whole line of a table that matches the maximum of a value

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

## Problem

I have a table with 3 data:

- A is text
- B is number
- H is text

I want with QUERY in GoogleSheets recover the column H grouped by A that has the max of B

```
=QUERY(resume!A2:H;"select A,Max(B) where A<>'' group by A ";1)
```

is working perfectly but I can't see H

```
=QUERY(resume!A2:H;"select A,Max(B),H where A<>'' group by A ";1)
```

is not working. Error H needs aggregation

```
=QUERY(resume!A2:H;"select A,Max(B),H where A<>'' group by A,H ";1)
```

is showing me each line of A and H that are different. That means I have all the lines

```
#Example:#
Source Table
[A] 	 [B]	 [H]
S01 	 10	 A
S01 	 8	 B
S02 	 20	 C
S02 	 7	 D

#wished result for QUERY#
[A] 	 [B] 	 [H]
S01 	 10 	 A
S02 	 20 	 C
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SORT(SORTN(SORT({A2:B, H2:H}, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 0), 1, 1)
```

[image: 0]